# How to give the focus (back) to my Visual Studio tool window

Tags: visual-studio, async-await, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

My project is a Visual Studio Extension which has a tool window. The tool window contains a grid control. A line in the grid corresponds to some part of a source code file, XAML file, ASP file or WinForms UI.

When you click in a cell in the grid, I want to find the corresponding think in your project, open it, select it, but afterwards I want the focus to be in the cell where you originally clicked, in the grid, in my tool window.

This used to work, but it is not working in my current version, in particular after selecting text in a XAML file.

To select text in the XAML file, I

- start with the ProjectItem
- open the corresponding window
- activate it with window.Activate()
- get the TextDocument object
- manipulate the TextDocument.Selection to select text

After that I set the focus back to my tool window, by

- casting the ToolWindowPane to IVsWindowFrame
- calling the show method IVsWindowFrame.Show()
- possibly setting the focus to a specific control in my tool window (but that is not really relevant)

I have made (at least) three significant changes:

- I am using Visual Studio 2019
- I am using async and await at a lot of places (but still running on the main thread)
- My top level control is now a WPF control. Formerly it was WinForms

Maybe Visual Studio 2019 is doing something asynchronous in the XAML window, which was previously synchronous. This might mean that I set the focus back to my tool window, but lose it again immediately.

Is there a better way to force the focus back to my tool window?

Alternatively, is there some event I should wait for, before calling IVsWindowFrame.Show()?

Comment: Inserting **Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100)** before calling **IVsWindowFrame.show()** effectively fixes the problem with regard to the XAML window, but it is not a very satisfying implementation.

Comment: Maybe this issue have something to do with [new feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/new-features-for-extension-authors-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-1/) in VS2019? Like Per-monitor awareness.